# Want to change Game Category with new Update

Tags: ios, itunes

We already published a 3D Infinite runner game on App Store. When we published the game we chose ACTION and ARCADE category but Apple automatically add out game in to Kids Section as well as 5 & Under Section..

Now we want to do new update and want to remove 5&under as well as Kids section. We only want Action or Arcade category also We want to showcase ads and have in-app purchases but do not want to give parental gate as we want to game for adults only.

So kindly help us what we can do? If we directly upload the updated version than will that be accepted by Apple? What options do we need to choose, so that it won't consider as kids Game? Do we need to make any changes in selection?

Please guide.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you edit this - are you looking for the procedure to leave the old category and have your app placed in a new category or are you basically looking to have one app listed twice? It's not clear if you are branding each differently or just changing things since you know duplicate submissions is discouraged and potentially abuse of the current terms?

Answer (score 1):

As Apple added the category, you need to talk to Apple. See [How to Contact Us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/):

> ### App Store
>
> …
>
> - [Tunes Connect](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus/)
>
>   For questions about getting started with iTunes Connect, setting up test user accounts, or submitting your app.

Apple's iTunes Connect team will answer your questions and help you.